# React with chakra doesn't trigger useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, chakra-ui

I'm doing first steps on using chakra ui with create-react-app.
The UI would be a live data viewer (using react-plotly).
The socket.io server emits new json data each second if triggered by a send_plot_data emit and the ui should plot the data using plotly-react

Without chakra code below works like a charm.
With chakra the socket.emit lines to request configuration (get_config) and request plot data (send_plot_data) don't get triggered (I looked in the socket.io server logs).

Most of the code below (except buttons, which should also trigger some emit's and populate dropbox options according to the received JSON data)

Why is this code not working as supposed to be with chakra ? without chakra it works.
Is there an easy fix ?

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import {io} from 'socket.io-client';
import Plot from 'react-plotly.js';

import {
  ChakraProvider, Flex, Box, Spinner, Container, Text
} from '@chakra-ui/react';

const socket = io("http://192.168.0.101:5000");

const App = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
      socket.on("connect",()=>{
        console.log(`Connected`);
        socket.emit("send_plot_data", {symbol: "default"});
        socket.emit("get_config", {config: ""});
      });
      socket.on("do_graph", res => {
        console.log(`Graph plot ok`)
        if(loading===true){
          setLoading(false);
        }
        let response = JSON.parse(res);
        response.config = {responsive: true}
        setData(response);
      });
      socket.on("connect_error", (err) => {
        console.log(`connect_error due to ${err.message}`);
      });
      return () => socket.disconnect();

  //eslint-disable-next-line
  }, []);

  return (
   <ChakraProvider resetCSS>
         <Box>
             {loading?(
                <Flex flexDirection="column" alignItems="center">
                  <Container minHeight="10vh">
                  </Container>
                  <Spinner />
                  <Text fontSize='lg'> Loading plot data ... </Text>
                </Flex>
              ):(
                <Plot {...data} />
              )}
          </Box>
    </ChakraProvider>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems to be a problem with React 18.

Downgraded to 17 with MUI instead of 18 and chakra and works.

chakra (even v1) needs framer-motion.
framer-motion needs react 18

```
Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^18.0.0" from framer-motion@8.1.7
npm ERR! node_modules/framer-motion
npm ERR!   framer-motion@"*" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer framer-motion@">=4.0.0" from @chakra-ui/react@2.4.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/@chakra-ui/react
npm ERR!     @chakra-ui/react@"*" from the root project
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe try to move the creation of the socket inside the `useEffect`

```
const socket = io("http://192.168.0.101:5000");
```

looks like the `connect` event triggered before the app component is mounted and no one listens to it...

Comment: if I place the creation of the socket in the useEffect function it becomes a missing dependency.
"React Hook useEffect has a missing dependency: 'socket'. Either include it or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps"

Comment: add ignore this eslint rule has sometimes false positives, in this case you want to useEffect to run only on first mount